# Understanding git pull and git fetch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I understand that `git fetch` downloads the data from the remote repository and only updates the remote-tracking branches, not yet merging into the local branches (thic can be done with `git merge local_branch origin/remote_branch`). And that `git pull` does all of this at once.

But I want to know: do both of these command download a single branch? Or do they download the entire remote repository (and in the case of `git pull`, merge it) at once?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git fetch` fetches **all** branches and tags from the remote repository (but as you say, it does not merge the changes into local branches).

`git pull` does this fetch (of all branches and tags) and then merges **only the current branch**.

Comment: It fetches them all by default, but you can have it fetch anything you want by changing the default in `remote.$name.fetch` or explicitly on the command line.